# AngularJS: Clearing input box using ngClick

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am having issues with clearing a search input box using ngClick.

#### search.html

```
<label for="search" class="item item-input">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Search" name="search" ng-model="searchPosts" />
  <img ng-show="searchPosts.length >= 1" ng-click="resetSearch()" src="icons/x-ico.png" alt="Clear search bar" class="cross-icon" />
  <img ng-hide="searchPosts.length >= 1" src="icons/search-orange.png" alt="Enter a search term" class="search-icon" />
</label>
```

#### controllers.js

```
$scope.resetSearch = function() {
  $scope.searchPosts = '';
}
```

In the HTML, if I place the image outside of the `<label>` tags then it works fine (clears the input box), but not when it's inside. Is there a particular reason for this?

Comment: is function `$scope.resetSearch()` call when click on that image?

Comment: EDIT: actually it works fine, http://plnkr.co/edit/iT5OXRgulKMY5NoUUcnr?p=preview as soon as you type in the box the image changes to the one with reset function and clears the model

Comment: @maurycy Hmm... that is very strange. I can't get it to work in my dev environment or iOS simulator.

Comment: Check for typos in function name and if it's on the same scope

Comment: The resetSearch seems to work for me.  Is there still an issue with this plunker?